# ASP.NET MVC 5 Identity 2.0 Set Initial User Password

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've built an MVC 5 website. Adding a user generates and sends an email with a confirmation token. When the user clicks the emailed link, the site responds, asking the user to set an initial password.

When the user tries to set an initial password, the user has not logged in yet, so `User.Identity.GetUserId()` is `null`. How do I pass the user ID from the confirmation link to the call to `SetPassword()`?

#### AccountController.cs

```cs
// GET: /Account/ConfirmEmail
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
{
    if (userId == null || code == null)
        return View("Error");

    var result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);
    if (result.Succeeded)
        using (var s = new UserStore())
        {
            var u = s.FindByIdAsync(userId).Result;
            await s.SetEmailConfirmedAsync(u, true);
            return View("ConfirmEmail", new { Id = userId }); // This doesn't seem to make Id available.
        }
    else
        return View("Error");
}
```

#### ConfirmEmail.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Confirm Email";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<div>
    <p>
        Thank you for confirming your email.
        Please @Html.ActionLink("click here to create a password.",
            "SetPassword", "Manage",
            routeValues: null, // I've tried passing new { Id = Model.Id }, but Id isn't available at run-time.
            htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })
    </p>
</div>
```

#### ManageController.cs

```cs
// POST: /Manage/SetPassword
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> SetPassword(SetPasswordViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await UserManager.AddPasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.NewPassword);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Message = ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess });
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix is to add a parameter to the SetPassword method:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SetPassword(SetPasswordViewModel model, Guid userIdentifier)
```

The ConfirmEmail.cshtml would then change to:

```
   Please @Html.ActionLink("click here to create a password.",
        "SetPassword", "Manage",
        routeValues: null, // I've tried passing new { Id = Model.Id }, but Id isn't available at run-time.
        htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink", userIdentifier = Model.ID })
```

When the user clicks the link, you should now have the userIdentifier filled in with the ID of the user the email was sent to.

It's not super secure as they can pass any Guid (if they can figure out which one to send).

You may want to track a PasswordRequest object by ID (instead of userIdentifier) that can expire the email in which case they need to request a new one. This way once the PasswordRequest record is used, it can be deleted to prevent reuse as well.

Note: PasswordRequest is just a made up name.

Comment: `Model.ID` isn't available at run-time. Am I missing something?

Comment: Use whatever tracking token you want to pass to find the user later.

Answer (score 0):

You collect the password when you first create a user so that you don't need an id for your `UserManager.CreateAsync()`. You'd send the confirmation email token in the register action after you've created a new row (and generated the id).

The `SetPassword()` action is for an **existing and authenticated** user to change their password. You should not mark that as `[AllowAnonymous]`.

Comment: Site administrators will create the user accounts. Administrators don't want to deal with passwords. Is there no idiomatic way for a user to create one's own password upon email-confirmation of the account?

Comment: Devise a system to generate first-time passwords. Then just have the admins register the new user with the generated password and mark the account as unverified. The first time the user logs-in they are forced to update the password.

Comment: The way you have your `SetPassword()` action setup now, a malicious user could try any id and update passwords.

Comment: I appreciate that insight. I wondered if I were trying to use the built-in functionality inappropriately.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the query string, in the confirmation token you can encrypt the username or userid and when you reach the reset page decrypt it and set the `Identity` to whoever it was.

Edit: In addition to that you can create a new table in the database `InitialSetup`, with columns `user`, `EncryptedId(guid)`, `Initial`.

When someone clicks the email link they will need to input `username`, and new password. That is when you will check if the input username is the same as the `EncryptedId(guid)`.

Comment: Lol! This is what I tried first. Unfortunately, I didn't get it right. After reading your response, I took another shot at it, and it worked. The warning that this is not secure, however, has me rethinking this approach. So I'm not sure which response to mark as the answer just yet.